# Creating a graph with a "peak" value (x-axis from 0 to 100 to 0)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to create a graph whose x-axis will start from 0, peak at 100, and then return to 0 - all from left to right. An example is attached. How do I do this?

[image]

### Data:

```
Applied Voltage Capacitance

1.96    23.311
2.74    23.310
3.50    23.311
4.29    23.311
5.07    23.310
6.22    23.310
7.06    23.310
8.16    23.310
9.28    23.309
10.10   23.309
10.90   23.308
12.40   23.306
13.10   23.306
14.00   23.305
15.10   23.319
16.30   23.357
17.50   23.382
16.60   23.348
15.30   23.302
14.30   23.302
13.20   23.301
12.00   23.302
10.90   23.303
9.71    23.303
8.94    23.304
7.77    23.304
7.04    23.305
5.86    23.305
4.70    23.306
3.90    23.305
3.03    23.306
1.96    23.310
1.20    0.000
```

Comment: Creating the graph really isn't the problem if you have the data. So... where is the data?

Comment: Data added, although I cant seem to format them to a table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean something like this:

[image]

Then you just need to setup a category column, like col A, going from 0-to-100-to-0 and place your values accordingly.

When you setup your plot-data, use this category column as the input values for your x-axis.

*Edit:*

- create data like in the picture above for col a and b
- extend it to reach 100, then decreasingly extend it to reach 0
- now you should have data from row1 to row201
- select the data of column B
- go to the insert tab on the ribbon menu
- insert a line graph
- select the data-line with the peak
- right click and choos "select source"
- edit category setup to use A1-A201

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I set up the category column?

Comment: hope this clears it up - otherwise - some trial&error helps always a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Paste your data into Excel:
   [image]
2. Clean up (remove empty lines).
3. Select the content of the Capacitance column (except for the 0 value).
4. Insert a line chart:
   [image]
5. Edit the chart data:
   [image]
6. Edit the axis labels:
   [image]
7. Use your other column as labels:
   [image]

Be sure **not** to include your last (0) value. Otherwise it will break the scale of your graph.

Comment: +1 for the effort and the quite good tip at the end - by the way, do you use an english office or do you switch the language of excel when needed? If the latter - how? It's just because I always have to search and use some screenshots from the web, due to my german version.

Comment: @Jook: I use the English version. My setup is somewhat complex/weird :P Too weird to get into details in a comment ;D Feel free to drop by [chat] though ;)